# How to show every primitives in featuretools

Tags: python, featuretools

I want to list every built-in primitive in Featuretool without skip("...").
I know I can use list_primitives() but I don't know how to show everything.

```
import featuretools as ft

print(ft.primitives.list_primitives()) #show list of primitives with skip
```

I tried .set_option('display.max_rows', None) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, list_primitives() function only displays the first 20 primitives and uses the "..." to display others. You can modify the pandas options to show all the rows without truncation. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import featuretools as ft

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # show all rows
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)  # show full primitive name

primitives = ft.list_primitives()
primitives_df = pd.DataFrame(primitives)
print(primitives_df)
```